# Edit collection in separated ListBoxes

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged, itemssource, checkedlistbox

I have source elements like this:

`var collection = new ObservableCollection<SourceItems>(source);`

source implements **INotifyPropertyChanged**

I need to edit and view this collection in CheckListBoxes (listBox with checkBoxes from WPFToolKit)with rules:

- every CheckListBoxes must be sort by one of collection's field. Collection has order field for each CheckListBox. For example - ItemOrder.
- visible elements in one listBox depend on checked items from other.

Every CheckListBox has itemsSource

```
checkListBox1.ItemsSource=collection;
```

So, if i check items in one listBox i must see only checked items in other.
And every listBox must be sorted by one of source's field

- listBox1 by field orderItem
- listBox2 by field orderVisibleItem and so on.

User can move elements in each listBoxes and it must not affect ordering in other.

I tried create **CollectionViewSource**  for every ListBox. But when I sort one, it sort each other.

Linq for filtering and sortnig don't work too, because changes not updating dynamicly.

Is there best way to create such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CollectionViewSource`. 
I'm guessing that you used `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(.. )` ? you should create two NEW views for the collection:

```
CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = TheCollection };
```